# Отсеять элементы коллекции если элемент с таким id есть в списке

Tags: c#, linq, linq2db

Имеется лист, в нём объекты класса user{iduser, name} и 2 ой лист, в нём объекты класса useringroup{idgroup, iduser}. Нужно в листе c юзерами оставить только тех, id которых нет в useringroup.
Хотел сделать что то типо такого var a = users.Select(s => useringroup.Where(f => s.iduser!=f.iduser));
Но вышло не очень.... Результатом стало то, что в оказались тех кто есть в useringroup и само представление данных было не очень хорошим.

Comment: `Select` - сделать нужный вид. `Where` - взять объект, который удовлетворяет условию. Вам тут можно попробовать что-то по типу `var result = users.Where(x=>!useringroup.Any(g => g.IdUser == x.IdUser));`.

Comment: Уже часа 2 над этим сижу.... То нельзя применить != к элементам, то предикат не верный... Спасибо))!

Answer (score 0):

Если решать задачу в SQL стиле, надо предварительно объединить оба списка, и исключить те элементы, которые имеют совпадения в обоих списках:

```cs
var filteredList = from u in userList
                   join g in useringroupList on u.iduser equals g.iduser into ug
                   where !ug.Any()
                   select u;
```

Если не нравится SQL стиль, этот код можно переписать иначе:

```cs
var filteredList = userList.GroupJoin(useringroupList, u => u.iduser, g => g.iduser, (u, gs) => new { u, hasGroup = gs.Any() })
    .Where(x => !x.hasGroup)
    .Select(x => x.u);
```

Однако в таком стиле код станет гораздо понятнее если не использовать join вовсе, а применить метод Any прямо к списку useringroupList.

```cs
var filteredList = userList.Where(u => !useringroupList.Any(g => g.iduser == u.iduser));
```